# Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Show that {$x-f(x): |x|\leq 1$} is a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

**Question**:

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Show that {$x-f(x): |x|\leq 1$} is a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$.

**Attempt**:

If $f(x)$ is a continuous function, $f(x)$ is bounded. Let $|f(x)|\leq M$.

Then, $|x-f(x)|\leq |x|+|f(x)|=|x|+M$. Since $|x|$ is bounded by $1$, $|x-f(x)|$ is also bounded.

I'm having difficulty trying to find a reason why it's a closed set. Maybe using the inverse image of $f(x)$?

Comment: Have you covered (in your class/the relevant chapter) the theorem that the image of a compact set under a continuous function is compact?

Answer (score 2):

The set is the image of a continuous function : x -f(x) over a closed interval.So it is also a closed interval : if the function takes two values it takes all the values between them and it has maximum and minimum (Weierstrass theorem).

Comment: @Don ANtonio :thanks